# Unresolved External Symbol for gluPerspective in CUDA project

Tags: opengl, cuda, unresolved-external

Actually, I know it's a popular linking problem, which regularly can be resolved by adding #pragma(lib, "glu32.lib") or adding glu32.lib in Visual studio configuration.

However, my problem is strange and solutions above is useless.

I added some extra files containing OpenGL functions like gluPerspective and gluBuild2DMipmaps to the CUDA project, the VolumeRender, which is from CUDA SDK.

After compiling, I found those extra files would occur the Unresolved External Symbol error for glu functions. However, when I put these glu functions into the original Cpp file, it works fine.

I have ever tried two solutions above but useless. Could anyone give me a hint to solve this puzzle?

Comment: The header file is called `Glu.h` and the library `Glu32.lib` (note the case). Are you sure you have those correct in your code and project?

Comment: Yes, I think those are all correct. The point is, I can use glu function in the original cpp file but not in my own cpp file. How strange it is, dude.

Comment: you should give some detailed information about you linkage and `#include` hierarchy and some necessary code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I gave up. I tried to add the CUDA part into the OpenGL projects. It worked fine!